# How to call a popup form DataReader from CellClick Event

Tags: c#

When I pass the value from the calling form to the popup, the value is received, but when the code reaches the while (drInsiderInfo.Read) statement it bounces back to insiderPopUp.ShowDialog on the calling form and the DataReader is never executed.

Here is my CellClick event code:

```
        private void allInsiderTransactionsDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string passedInsider;

        try
        {
            passedInsider = allInsiderTransactionsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            DataGridViewCell cellClicked = (DataGridViewCell)allInsiderTransactionsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (cellClicked.ColumnIndex == this.allInsiderTransactionsDataGridView.Columns["Insider"].Index) 
            {
                frmInsiderPopUp insiderPopUp = new frmInsiderPopUp(passedInsider);
                insiderPopUp.passedNumber = passedInsider;
                insiderPopUp.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

And here is my popup form DataReader code:

```
        public string passedNumber { get; set; }

    public frmInsiderPopUp(string passedNumber)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        passedInsiderNumberTextBox.Text = passedNumber;
        populateVipNumberTextBoxes();

    }

    public void populateVipNumberTextBoxes()
    {

        if (passedInsiderNumberTextBox.Text != null) 

        connect.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand insiderStProc = new SqlCommand("RMM3InsiderInformation");
            insiderStProc.Connection = connect;
            insiderStProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            insiderStProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsiderNumber", passedInsiderNumberTextBox.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader drInsiderInfo = insiderStProc.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (drInsiderInfo.Read())
                {
                    insiderNameTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Name"].ToString();
                    insiderStoreTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Store"].ToString();
                    insiderPhoneTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Phone"].ToString();
                    insiderStreetTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Street"].ToString();
                    insiderSuiteTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Apt"].ToString();
                    insiderCityTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["City"].ToString();
                    insiderStateTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["State"].ToString();
                    insiderZipCodeMaskedTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["ZipCode"].ToString();
                    insiderEmailTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Email"].ToString();
                    insiderSignUpDateMaskedTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["DateIn"].ToString();
                    insiderLastMailedMaskedTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["LastMailed"].ToString();
                    insiderTotalTransactionsTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["TotalTrans"].ToString();
                    insiderTotalDollarsTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["TotalDollars"].ToString();
                    insiderColorTextBox.Text = drInsiderInfo["Color"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
           connect.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize the variable connect?

Comment: Globally, at the top of each form. The connection string is:  SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=True;");

Comment: The datareader has no rows.

Comment: Thank you for your question, Steve. You started me thinking down another path where I discovered the issue was actually a problem in my stored procedure. I was trying to get the value of the wrong column. Embarrassed, but happy to be moving on. Thank you!